# Dagger 2 android object null

Tags: android, inject, dagger-2

I have a custom class Fragment AFragment that has an injected attribute : AController controller.

The problem is that when I call this : controller.onStart() --> controller is null.

The code :

Class AFragment :

```
public class AFragment extends Fragment {

@Inject
AController controller;

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    controller.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    controller.onCreate();
}
}
```

Class AController :

```
public class AController {


private final DataInteractor dataInteractor;

@Inject
public AController(DataInteractor dataInteractor){
    this.dataInteractor = dataInteractor;
}

public void onCreate(){

}

public void onStart(){

}
}
```

Comment: Where do you actually call the method that does the injecting?

Comment: I am a newbie in android, I have no idea where the injection occurs and don't really know how they work.

Comment: So you shouldn't use Dagger. It's for expirienced users and difficult to master.

Comment: I agree with Damian, you probably should learn the basics of Android before you get into the more advanced techniques.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need is create a component and inject  AFragment into it.

```
@Singleton
@Component
public interface ApplicationComponent {  
    void inject(AFragment fragment);
}
```

Because in AController class you make a Constructor inject so you don't need to make a module for your component.

And also you need to create the component when application start. So just init it in your Application extended class.

```
public class DemoApplication extends Application {  
    private ApplicationComponent mComponent;

    @Override 
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                    .build();
    }

    public ApplicationComponent getComponent() { 
        return mComponent;
    }
}
```

The last step is what i say before, inject AFragment into the component.

```
public class AFragment extends Fragment {

@Inject
AController controller;

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    controller.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ((DemoApplication) getApplication()).getComponent().inject(this);
    controller.onCreate();
}
}
```